Is thre a way how to insert Loop component into SharePoint online without top & side menu?
we are using simple embed web part feature with
<iframe src="component" height="700px" width="100%"></iframe>
tag to insert a Loop component into SharePoint online page inside modern (communication type) web. Is there a way how to insert just a content without top or side app menu? Or more parameters for iframe tag that we can use?

... the tricky part is, using the same iframe tag, some users can see the menues, some don't. And it is not because of rights, that we tested like a first thing.

The goal is clear: Our managers wants to have unified look for all users and with no app menues.

I also interested in the answer....
